# LDA: sample mean of two distributions are proportional

Tags: distributions, discriminant-analysis, latent-dirichlet-alloc

I came up with a discussion around what does it mean that the sample mean of two distributions are proportional. This discussion started when talking about linear discriminant analysis and how this proportionality may affect to the calculations of the discriminants.

Imagine we have two distributions that are scattered in a 2D plot and they are separated by some distance. Both means are separated by a distance d and somehow, they are proportional.

My question here is... if two variables are correlated, I assume that both central points (means) are also correlated and so, they are proportional. But is this assumption always true? Because, could both variables be related and their sample mean not proportional? Please, refer to the image below to get an idea of what I am explaining. In the plot both clusters are separated and I can assume their central points are proportional, but is there any case in which they are not?ç

[image]

If I make such assumption for a Linear Discriminant Analysis, isn't it naive to consider that if both sample means are proportional, the whole analysis could be simplified in the maximization functions....

I don't know if I was clear, I am not very duche in the topic so apologies for the possible mistakes.

Comment: The intended meaning of "somehow, they are proportional" is unclear to me.  Can you explain in what sense this holds?

Comment: This holds on the assumption that μ1 being the sample mean of cluster 1 and μ2 the sample mean of cluster 2, the μ1 = α * μ2, on each of the dimensions. That is that if the sample mean of one of the cluster is varied, the other cluster also varies its mean by a factor α.

Comment: Thanks! Note that the population means $\mu_1,\mu_2$ are not correlated, they're fixed parameters. Aside from that proportionality, do the usual LDA assumptions hold (e.g. same variance covariance matrix for each cluster, independence of observations, multivariate normality?)

Comment: Mmm could you elaborate on the fixed parameters? if we were able to track that sample mean as we are adding points to the cluster in time, we would expect to have such relationship between the two means, right? i.e.  $\mu_1$ increases as dependent on time (t) and $\mu_2$ should be modified accordingly, increasing or reducing the distance or moving in the plane. If both variables are not correlated, then they should not show such dependence?

Comment: $\mu$ is a population quantity (an attribute of an underlying process), not a sample statistic; for that you would use a symbol like $\bar{Y}$.